# how can I convert rows with date range to rows with each date in rage?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following data pulled from a database:

```
data = [ 
    {'db_id': 1, 'start': '2020-02-02', 'end': '2020-02-05'},
    {'db_id': 2, 'start': '2020-02-04', 'end': '2020-02-06'},
    {'db_id': 3, 'start': '2020-02-02', 'end': '2020-02-04'}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to convert this into a row for each `date`/`db_id` combination, inclusive of the start and end date.  So I want to end up with the following DataFrame:

```
result_data = [
    {'db_id': 1, 'date': '2020-02-02'},
    {'db_id': 1, 'date': '2020-02-03'},
    {'db_id': 1, 'date': '2020-02-04'},
    {'db_id': 1, 'date': '2020-02-05'},
    {'db_id': 2, 'date': '2020-02-04'},
    {'db_id': 2, 'date': '2020-02-05'},
    {'db_id': 2, 'date': '2020-02-06'},
    {'db_id': 3, 'date': '2020-02-02'},
    {'db_id': 3, 'date': '2020-02-03'},
    {'db_id': 3, 'date': '2020-02-04'},
]

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result_data)
```

What is an efficient way to do this in pandas (the data set has several hundred thousand rows).

Comment: I don't understand the logic between the `df` and `result_df`

Comment: The df has a start date, and and end date for each `db_id`, for example for `db_id=1`, the start is feb 2, and the end is feb 5.  I need a new dataframe with a row for each date that each `db_id` was active.  So in the case of `db_id=1`, there would be a row for feb 2, feb 3, feb 4, and feb 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `resample`, but first you need to make sure that your date are of `datetime` type:

```
df['start'], df['end'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start']), pd.to_datetime(df['end'])

(df.melt(id_vars='db_id', value_name='date')
   .set_index('date')
   .groupby('db_id')['variable'].resample('D').ffill()
   .reset_index()
   .drop('variable',axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   db_id       date
0      1 2020-02-02
1      1 2020-02-03
2      1 2020-02-04
3      1 2020-02-05
4      2 2020-02-04
5      2 2020-02-05
6      2 2020-02-06
7      3 2020-02-02
8      3 2020-02-03
```

Or you can also do a simple `for` loop:

```
pd.concat(pd.DataFrame({'db_id':x['db_id'], 
                        'date':pd.date_range(x['start'], x['end'], freq='D')}
                        ) 
          for _, x in df.iterrows()
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct a new dataframe from genex

```
df_final = pd.DataFrame(((i, d) for i, s, e in zip(df.db_id, df.start, df.end) 
                                    for d in pd.date_range(s, e, freq='D')), 
                        columns=['db_id', 'date'])

Out[90]:
   db_id       date
0      1 2020-02-02
1      1 2020-02-03
2      1 2020-02-04
3      1 2020-02-05
4      2 2020-02-04
5      2 2020-02-05
6      2 2020-02-06
7      3 2020-02-02
8      3 2020-02-03
9      3 2020-02-04
```